# Unmarshalling an array is not giving me any values

Tags: java, json, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

When I unmarshal my JSON, the Warehouses instance is ok with however many warehouse instances are in it's list.

Each warehouse instance has the url field but the WarehouseField list has one instance with blank values.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**JSON**

```
{
    "warehouses": [
        {
            "warehouse": {
                "PRiyA": "0",
                "WHID": "1 ALABO",
                "PRixA": ""
            },
            "url": "http://ACL-HPDV6:8080/HSyncREST/api/v1/warehouses/PLL/1 ALABO"
        },
        {
            "warehouse": {
                "PRiyA": "0",
                "WHID": "1000 EDWAR",
                "PRixA": ""
            },
            "url": "http://ACL-HPDV6:8080/HSyncREST/api/v1/warehouses/PLL/1000 EDWAR"
        },
    ],
    "url": "http://ACL-HPDV6:8080/HSyncREST/api/v1/warehouses/PLL",
    "status": " "
}
```

**Code used to unmarshall**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Class<?>[] ctx = {Warehouses.class, Warehouse.class, WarehouseField.class};
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ctx);
  Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
  um.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
  um.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
  Source json = new StreamSource(new File("D:/warehouses.json"));
  Warehouses warehouses = um.unmarshal(json, Warehouses.class).getValue();
```

**Model classes**

```
public class Warehouses {
    public List<Warehouse> warehouses;
    public String url;
    public String status;
    <getters and setters>
}

public class Warehouse {
    public List<WarehouseField> warehouse;
    public String url;
    <getters and setters>
}

public class WarehouseField {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String implName;
    @XmlValue
    public String value;
    <getters and setters>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you make all fields private, you have getters & setters for your fields.

It is a also a good idea to separate the response(?) DTO class name from the field and actual type naming.

Assuming that field names in the response DTOs tell the actual type, then do a bit refactoring like `Warehouses` to `WarehousesResponse` and `Warehouse` to `WarehouseResponse`.

Then about the "array", clip from the JSON:

```
"warehouse": {
    "PRiyA": "0",
    "WHID": "1 ALABO",
    "PRixA": ""
}
```

this is not an array named warehouse so it not deserializing to a `List` nicely.

It is an Object of type `Warehouse` (that is why distinction WarehouseResponse, for clarity but see also mention about `Map` later) that is a field named warehouse in Object of type `WarehouseResponse` (assuming you agree on naming policy).

One option is to create a class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Warehouse {
    private String PRiyA;
    private String WHID;
    private String PRixA;
}
```

and change WarehouseResponse like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class WarehouseResponse {
// Change the list to warehouse object as it is in response
//      private List<WarehouseField> warehouse; 
    private Warehouse warehouse;
    private String url;
    private Date date = new Date();

}
```

Usually it is also possible to set key/value-pairs simply - for an example - to a `Map<String,String>` so in this case `WarehouseResponse`s could also have `private HashMap<String, String> warehouse` and no class `Warehouse` would be needed. However I could not  get it working  with my `Moxy` knowledge.

So I presented how you can deserialize (and serialize) the format you gave in your JSON but I can not know it this then suits your possible `XML` needs

Comment: Thank you.  The Map would suit my needs much better and my initial attempts failed.  Perhaps someone with MOXY expertise can elaborate on the MAP